# How to return available filters along with search query in elastic search

Tags: javascript, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Basically im pretty new to elastic search and need some help in querying. Also let me know if i need to make any changes to my MongoDB Schema

I want to know how do i search in elastic search which would give me available products based on query and filters available to filter

something like

```
{
  products: [{...}, {...}, ...],
  filters: [ ... ]
}
```

**product** Schema is

```
    {
      title: "...",
      description: "...",
      categoryId: ObjectId
      variants: [ variant1ID, variant2ID ],
     ... other miscellaneous stuff
   }
```

**Variant** Schema is

```
{
 product : objectId,
 image: ..,
 price: ..., 
 attributes:[
   "SIZE-XL", // note: these are facetId , i can popuplate these to {name:"SIZE", value:"XL"}
   "COLOR-BLUE",
    ....and so on
 ]
}
```

First i taught to retrive filters based on category, because each category has a fixed number of facets , then i realiased , search query doesnt really have to be specific to category,

Also i am thinking to store product in elastic in below format

```
 { 
     productId: "...",
     title:"..",
     description: "...",
     categoryId: "....",
     image: "..",
     variantId:"..."
     price:"..",
     attributes: [
     {
      name:"SIZE",
      value:"XL",
     },
     {
      name:"COLOR",
      value:"BLUE",
     }
      .
      .
      .
      ]
}
```

basically storing each variant as seperately with its product title and description, So searching is fast and easier

Comment: Isn't clear what is the question.

Comment: did you check aggregation in Elasticsearch ? it will provide you facets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. In Elasticsearch you want to avoid using populate/joins and you look for flattening/de-normalizing your data.

You can read this article to have a better idea about modeling variants:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-create-a-document-schema-for-product-variants-and-skus-for-your-ecommerce-search-experience

You can create a query that returns facets of every any you need, as long as a keyword type of that field exists (by default it does).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Then you can run a filter query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context

You want to use a "terms" query inside your filters because in most cases filters are exact matches (a checkbox in the UI) so this is the most efficient way to do it:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the guide, now im having `{...product, "attributes": [ { "name": "Color", "value": "Aqua Blue" }, { "name": "Gender", "value": "Female" }, { "name": "Occasion", "value": "Active Wear" }, { "name": "Size", "value": "10XL" } ]` after using `"aggs": { "filters": { "terms": { "field": "attributes.name" } } }`  i  get output as `"buckets": [ { "key": "Color", "doc_count": 3 }, { "key": "Gender", "doc_count": 3 }, { "key": "Occasion", "doc_count": 3 }, { "key": "Size", "doc_count": 3 } ]` any idea how i could get values also along with keys like`[ { key: Color, values:["X","m"],count:3}]`

Comment: tried this tho `{ "aggs": { "filters": { "terms": { "field": "attributes.name" }, "aggs": { "values": { "terms": { "field": "attributes.value", "size": 10 } } } } }}` but it returns every other value along with each key

Comment: You can nest aggregations, so you can see sizes between each color: 

{
  "aggs": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 10
      },
      "colors_x_sizes": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "size"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

You can mark this answer as correct and open a new one with more context about your questions to help more people