# Elastic search terms aggregation for getting filter options

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

im trying to implement product searching and want to get search results along with filters to filter from. i have managed to get the filter keys [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611442/how-to-return-available-filters-along-with-search-query-in-elastic-search/74614506?noredirect=1#comment131733594_74614506), but also want values of those keys

my product body is

```
 {
      ...product,
       "attributes": [
            {
              "name": "Color",
              "value": "Aqua Blue"
            },
            {
              "name": "Gender",
              "value": "Female"
            },
            {
              "name": "Occasion",
              "value": "Active Wear"
            },
            {
              "name": "Size",
              "value": "0"
            }
          ],
 }
```

and im using the this query in es

```
GET product/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "filters": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attributes.name"
      
      },
      "aggs": {
        "values": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.value",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

Not sure why, but im getting all values for each key

```
 "aggregations": {
    "filters": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Color",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "values": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Active Wear",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Aqua Blue",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Female",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "0",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "10XL",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Gender",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "values": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Active Wear",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Aqua Blue",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Female",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "0",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "10XL",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Occasion",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "values": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Active Wear",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Aqua Blue",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Female",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "0",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "10XL",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Size",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "values": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Active Wear",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Aqua Blue",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "Female",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "0",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "10XL",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Also i do not want to specify manually all keys **explicitly** like **Color, Size** to get their respective values each.
Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, if you dont add a filter in a query clause you will see all the values. Aggs will only group the results.

Comment: Could you give an example. what do i even add in filters. im assuming i have no idea about the available keys before like Color, Size etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things simple must you use a single field to store attributes:

`"gender":"Male"`

I assume you have tons of attributes so you create an array instead, to handle that you will have to use "nested" field type.

Nested type preserves the relation between each of the nested document properties. If you dont use nested you will see all the properties and values mixed and you will not be able to aggregate by a property without manually adding filters.

You can read an article I wrote about that here:

https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-architecture/elasticsearch-nested-field-object-field/

Mappings :

```
PUT test_product_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will only show Red products of size XL and aggregate by attributes.

If you want to do OR's instead of AND's you must use "should" clauses instead of "filter" clauses.

Query

```
POST test_product_nested/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributes.name.keyword": "Color"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributes.value.keyword": "Red"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributes.name.keyword": "Size"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributes.value.keyword": "XL"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "attributes": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attributes"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributes.value.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_product_nested",
        "_id": "aJRayoQBtNG1OrZoEOQi",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Product 1",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "name": "Color",
              "value": "Red"
            },
            {
              "name": "Gender",
              "value": "Female"
            },
            {
              "name": "Occasion",
              "value": "Active Wear"
            },
            {
              "name": "Size",
              "value": "XL"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "attributes": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "name": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Color",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "values": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "Red",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Gender",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "values": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "Female",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Occasion",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "values": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "Active Wear",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Size",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "values": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "XL",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much..!  I actually tried using nested, but was getting 0 results, because i had not added "nested" inside aggs